AOP @afterReturning not been called
I'm learning some AOP concepts and I'm using annotation @AfterReturning on a method but, this advice is not been called after returning. Rest all are working fine. please refer the code below:-
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAspect {
    @Before("execution(* com.example.aop.service.*.*(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        //prints the method along with class name - Entering method: PaymentServiceImpl.makePayment(..)
        System.out.println("Entering method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString());
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        // prints the argument passed to method - Argument passed to makePayment: - 1000
        for(Object argument: args) System.out.println("Argument passed to "+joinPoint.getSignature().getName()+": - "+argument);
    }
    
    @After("execution(* com.example.aop.service.*.*(..))")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
            //prints after the method has been executed.
            System.out.println("Exiting method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString());
    }
    
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(String com.example.aop.service.PaymentServiceImpl.getCurrency()", returning = "result")
    public void logAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint,String result) {
            //prints after the method has been executed.
           System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature().getName()+" returns "+result);
    }
}

PaymentServiceImpl.java code: -
@Service
public class PaymentServiceImpl implements PaymentService {
    @Override
    public void makePayment(int amount) {
    String currency = getCurrency();
        System.out.println(amount+" "+currency+": amount debited");
        try {
            System.out.println("Processing");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
        }
        System.out.println(amount+" "+currency+": amount credited");

    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return "Rs";
    }

}
